# Сравнение элемента массива с диапазоном второго массива C#

Tags: c#, winforms

Всем доброго времени суток. Вот возник такой вопрос, как можно заменить конструкцию if..else. В данном случае выполняется определение или элемент первого массива входит в диапазонов, которые задаются элементами другого массива с помощью статической функции IsBetween ().

````
double[] windSpeed = new double[] { 5.74, 5.74, 3.45, 3.45, 5.74, 4.59, 6.89,
            3.45, 2.30, 2.30, 6.89, 5.74, 4.59, 6.89, 4.59, 3.45, 5.74, 4.59, 3.45,
            2.30, 3.45, 2.30, 6.89, 3.45, 5.74, 2.30, 4.59, 3.45, 3.45, 2.30, 4.59,
            3.45, 3.45, 4.59, 4.59, 2.30, 2.30, 2.30, 2.30, 0.57, 1.5, 7.8, 7, 1.5, 0.2, 4.5, 3.2, 10.0 };

 double[] upperLimits = new double[] { 0.0, 0.5, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0, 10.0, 11.0, 12.0, 13.0, 14.0, 15.0, 16.0, 17.0 };

public static class BetweenExtensions
    {
        public static bool IsBetween<T>(this T item, T start, T end)
        {
            return Comparer<T>.Default.Compare(item, start) >= 0
                && Comparer<T>.Default.Compare(item, end) <= 0;
        }
    }

public double[] CountsD(double[] windSpeed)
        {
            double[] numRepit = new double[upperLimits.Length];

            for (int i = 0; i < windSpeed.Length; i++)
            {
                if (arr[i].IsBetween(0, 0.5))
                {
                    numRepit[0] += 1.0;
                } else if (arr[i].IsBetween(0.5, 1))
                {
                    numRepit[1] += 1.0;
                } else if (arr[i].IsBetween(1, 2))
                {
                    numRepit[2] += 1.0;
                } else if (arr[i].IsBetween(2, 3))
                {
                    numRepit[3] += 1.0;
                } else if (arr[i].IsBetween(3, 4))
                {
                    numRepit[4] += 1.0;
                } else if (arr[i].IsBetween(4, 5))
                {
                    numRepit[5] += 1.0;
                } else if (arr[i].IsBetween(5, 6))
                {
                    numRepit[6] += 1.0;
                } else if (arr[i].IsBetween(6, 7))
                {
                    numRepit[7] += 1.0;
                } else if (arr[i].IsBetween(7, 8))
                {
                    numRepit[8] += 1.0;
                } else if (arr[i].IsBetween(8, 9))
                {
                    numRepit[9] += 1.0;
                } else if (arr[i].IsBetween(9, 10))
                {
                    numRepit[10] += 1.0;
                } else if (arr[i].IsBetween(10, 11))
                {
                    numRepit[11] += 1.0;
                } else if (arr[i].IsBetween(11, 12))
                {
                    numRepit[12] += 1.0;
                } else if (arr[i].IsBetween(12, 13))
                {
                    numRepit[13] += 1.0;
                } else if (arr[i].IsBetween(13, 14))
                {
                    numRepit[14] += 1.0;
                } else if (arr[i].IsBetween(14, 15))
                {
                    numRepit[15] += 1.0;
                } else if (arr[i].IsBetween(15, 16))
                {
                    numRepit[16] += 1.0;
                } else if (arr[i].IsBetween(16, 17))
                {
                    numRepit[17] += 1.0;
                }
            }

            return numRepit;
        }```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас в первом случае индекс зависит от начальной границы (0), во всех остальных - от конечной. Так как задача именно переписать код, добавим второй цикл по массиву границ от 1 элемента до предпоследнего:

```
for (int i = 0; i < windSpeed.Length; i++)
{
    if (arr[i].IsBetween(0, 0.5))
        numRepit[0] += 1.0;
    else
       for (int j = 1; j < upperLimits.Length - 1; j++)
       {
          if(arr[i].IsBetween(upperLimits[j], upperLimits[j +1]))
          {
             numRepit[j + 1] += 1.0;
             break;
          }
       }
}
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо)